# 504 Gateway Time-out nginx

Tags: apache, сервер

Посещаемость сервера VPS увеличилась до 2500 посетителей в день. 1-2 раза в сутки сервер перестает работать - выдает ошибку 504 Gateway Time-out nginx
Когда я перезагружаю сервер, сайт снова работает. Затем через 6 часов ошибка 504.
Какова может быть причина ошибки 504 Gateway Time-out nginx?

Операционная система: Debian 8 (64 bit)

Информация о сервере:

Количество процессов: 211

Оперативная память (использовано / всего): 1335904 / 24745248 kB

Панель управления: ISP manager Lite 5.56

Процессор: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz 2399.998 Mhz X 6

idle 94.81%

nice 0.00%

system 2.18%

user 3.02%

Размер дискового пространства 604621 Mb

/dev/sda1  /boot      31 / 225 Использовано/Всего (Mb)

/dev/sda2 /          197751 / 604395 Использовано/Всего (Mb)

Logs nginx error.log за 19 - 22

```
2017/12/22 07:51:28 [warn] 482#482: could not build optimal server_names_hash, you should increase either server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring server_names_hash_bucket_size
2017/12/22 07:51:28 [warn] 482#482: 4096 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024

2017/12/21 14:15:00 [warn] 477#477: could not build optimal server_names_hash, you should increase either server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring server_names_hash_bucket_size
2017/12/21 14:15:00 [warn] 477#477: 4096 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024
2017/12/21 20:31:24 [warn] 505#505: could not build optimal server_names_hash, you should increase either server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring server_names_hash_bucket_size
2017/12/21 20:31:24 [warn] 505#505: 4096 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024


2017/12/20 21:10:32 [warn] 511#511: could not build optimal server_names_hash, you should increase either server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring server_names_hash_bucket_size
2017/12/20 21:10:32 [warn] 511#511: 4096 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024

2017/12/19 08:29:07 [warn] 499#499: could not build optimal server_names_hash, you should increase either server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring server_names_hash_bucket_size
2017/12/19 08:29:07 [warn] 499#499: 4096 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024
2017/12/19 21:47:51 [warn] 514#514: could not build optimal server_names_hash, you should increase either server_names_hash_max_size: 512 or server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring server_names_hash_bucket_size
2017/12/19 21:47:51 [warn] 514#514: 4096 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024
```

Comment: Читайте логи (в первую очередь nginx error.log) и смотрите нагрузку, очевидно

Comment: Ошибки привел. Ваши рекомендации?

Comment: Это какие-то неправильные логи, в случае ошибки 504 nginx обязательно пишет в лог о каком-нибудь Connection timed out. Вы что-то не договариваете, но что, пока не знаю

Comment: Это логи определенные в nginx.conf # Определяем, куда писать лог ошибок и уровень логирования
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

Comment: Что у вас стоит за nginx'ом в качестве бекенда? Обычно на 504 отваливается бекенд, а nginx работает нормально -- просто по симптомам кажется, что именно Nginx поломался (а на деле просто это он сигнализирует) Но тут похоже на проблемы с ulimit

Comment: Nginx Frontend + Apache Backend

Comment: Хостинг рекомендует  увеличить мощность вашего VPS...